# Batch script for renaming files

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I need help regarding how to rename files automatically from a subfolders in the `C:\temp_download` which contains `res_save.0` in those folders. I want to rename it  as `nvm_res.0` and then subsequently `nvm_res.1`... `nvm_res.2`. When copying them to the folder `C:\temp`, it keep replacing. Can you help me with the wildcards? the code is below.

```
for /R "C:\temp_download" %%f in (res_save.*) do xcopy "%%f" "C:\temp\num_res.*" /Y
```

Comment: do you have `res_save.0` in different subfolders or `res_save.0`...`res_save.nn` in one (or more) subfolder(s)?

Comment: Yes, what are the input files (full relative paths please) and the output you expect?

Comment: you did not accept an answer until now. Maybe nobody will help you ..,

Comment: @ Endoro. I did! Why could I not? Can you tell me how to accept because I am new to this forum  joined 2 months ago. The res_save.0 upto res_save.nn are not subfolders, but are files. But they are inside diffrent folders at the location C:\temp_download. Thanks and much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an answer that solves your issue, make sure you accept the answer so that future searchers get an idea of which solution to try first.

This might do what you need.

```
@echo off
set c=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R "C:\temp_download" %%f in (res_save.*) do (
set /a c+=1
copy "%%f" "C:\temp\nvm_res.!c!" /Y >nul
)
```